# jQuery Reel Plugin: moving two reels at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-reel

Using the jQuery Reel Plugin I'm trying to make two reels to move at the same time.
Basically what I want is to control both reels at once so when I move one, the other one will move in sync as well. I need to use this in a stereoscopic related project.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpcdpc11/xR4TN/ . In this example I'm using two reels with the same images placed in a red background div and both of them have the area option set to the red div `data-area="#images_container"`. I'm no sure why it's not working properly... the first reels moves faster than the second but they should move in sync.

Does anyone have a better idea how to approach this? Maybe using the `area` option is not the best idea.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#master').on('frameChange', function () {
$('#slave').reel('frame', ($('#master').reel('frame')+0) );
});
```

This is working just fine. the +1 at the end was making one animation 1 frame ahead of the other. changed to 0 and now its fine.

I tried to use something like this myself and its not working for me. I want to overlay animations together Jpeg background, and PNGs on top all running when dragged will keep trying.

Comment: In the meantime Petr answer my problem personally and in the fiddle above you can see the solution.
The +1 at the end was intentional to make one reel ahead of the other. This is what I need in my project.